# How to disable GitHub cloning attempts and download from packagist only? (Can't update "private repos")

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using an internal repository which in turn connects to packagist.org. But sometimes when I run `update` commands, it will first try to clone some updated packages from GitHub, and it fails because there is no internet access to GitHub, so once it fails it tells me:

> Failed to download vendor/package from dist: curl error 28 while
> downloading from "some.GitHub.url"
>
> Now trying to download from source

But that attempt to download from GitHub takes very long time. How can I skip that part and directly make Composer download from the source (which I assume is from packagist)?

Update: Seems like I was wrong, the "source" is also not packagist. It still tries to clone from "source" on GitHub.. so it fails. It then fails twice, with the second message being:

> Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub
> credentials to access private repos

What does it mean? I can't update Laravel without using GitHub SSH keys? Can't do it somehow only using packagist?